# Combining cleveref and subref

Tags: subcaption, cleveref

I recently switched to using `cleveref` in my latex document. However, I have one case I still don't quite get right (or maybe it is just not covered in cleveref):

I use the `subfigure`-environment of the `subcaption`package on a regular basis. In the caption of the main figure, I then use `\subref{}` to get only the label of the subfigure, e.g. `(a)` instead of `1a`.
The main advantage of `cleveref` is that I can type `\cref{fig}` and get the result of `fig.~\ref{fig}`, but this does not work for a subreference, because `\cref` always produces the full label (`1a`).

Is there a way to reproduce `fig.~\subref{fig:a}` using cleveref as well? I.e. can I use `\cref` to create a reference than only uses the subfigure label without the mainfigure label?

**Edit**: here is a MWE illustrating the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-a}
        \caption{Figure 1a}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-b}
        \caption{Figure 1b}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Main figure caption}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

Using subcaption, I can link to \ref{fig}, \ref{fig:a} or to \subref{fig:a} alone.
Using cleverref, I can also link to \cref{fig} and to \cref{fig:a},
However, I cannot link to \subref{fig:a} alone.

\end{document}
```

This produces the following result:
[image]

**Edit 2**: To be extra clear: The point of using `cleveref` is to be able to write text references *without* the need to describe the nature of every label. But, if I can not create a subref version of the `cref` command, I am still stuck with manually typing those references, which, imho, makes not much sense. Either I use cleveref all the way, or not at all.
So the question is, can I create a `\cref` variant of `\subref`?

Comment: Could you provide a small, complete example?

Comment: I was hoping the problem was clear without a MWE, but here you go...

Comment: Can you clarify you MWE, i.e., bring it in line with the question? There is no `\label{fig:1a}` in MWE. Anyhow, what would you like to be the result of `\subref{fig:a}`? Also in your MWE you are just using the same command twice, i.e. `\subref{fig:a}`, in what respect do you expect it to give you a different result, the second time you invoke it? Are you saying you are missing a `\csubref{}`command? But again what would you like to see as a result? Imho saying fig. a is pretty meaningless in a document, because it does not refer to a distinct image, unless you intend to use it in the captions.

Comment: @MatthiasArras see my edit. Sry for the typo...
For what it's worth, I do not think saying "fig. a" in text is useless at all, if the figure number is clear from the context. And yes, you would definitely need such a command in a caption.

Answer (score 7):

A work around is to define your own 'partially-clever' command by adding this to the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\csubref}[2]{\namecref{#1}~\subref{#1:#2}}
```

However this requires a strict labelling scheme of the type mainfigurelabel:subfigureindex so if the total float is labeled by `fig` as in your example subfigures *must* be labeled as `fig:<your text here>`. You then may reference the subfloat by `\csubref{fig}{<your text here>}`. This does not take into account other useful features of `\cref` like handling of multiple references. Also I would consider using the subfig package as cleverref supports it natively, it does however not solve your 'problem'. But see below for comments on that.

Your accordingly modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand{\csubref}[2]{\namecref{#1}~\subref{#1:#2}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-a}
        \caption{Figure 1a}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-b}
        \caption{Figure 1b}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Main figure caption}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

Using subcaption, I can link to \ref{fig}, \ref{fig:a} or to \subref{fig:a} alone.
Using cleverref, I can also link to \cref{fig} and to \cref{fig:a},
However, I can link to \csubref{fig}{a} alone.

\end{document}
```

However, in the MWE you descirbed I am still not 100% convinced of the use case, since either

- In the captions it is redundant to refer to the figure again by using fig.
- When the figure number is deduced from the context, so may be the talking of a figure, too, so reproducing fig. may not add substantially.

The fact that the cleverref package in combination with the subfig package do not do what you want i.e. having 'fig. a' somewhere in the text add to my notion that it is not really needed to do so.

I would consider simply styling the subref a way that makes it more naturally familiar to the reader what `a` or `b` mean by using `\newcommand{\csubref}[1]{(\subref{#1})}` which gives `(a)` or `(b)` and is directly associated with a subfigure caption (this is the normal behavior for the subfig package). I agree, however, that a single a appearing somewhere in the text, as is the case when you use `\subref{fig:a}`, is undesirable, as it is always prone to be confused with the indefinite article 'a'.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. However, this newcommand of yours is not "smart" in the sense that I have to hardcode the `fig.~` part. I would need a second one for subtables, etc...

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect at least a limited degree of cleverness of the command. You should only need one for all kind of  labels now.

Comment: Thank you again, I should have thought about `\namecref` before. What do you mean cleveref supports subfig natively? Subgif has some serious disadvantages, first of all the limited hyperef support, and some even consider it deprecated (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats)

Comment: Also, I dont believe cleveref needs the labels to be formatted in the "fig:..." style to work properly, or so I believe. I can not test it right now

Comment: I agree. cleveref does not pose restrictions on the label format.  But the workaround I presented above does. With supporting natively I just mean that the cleveref manual says it it works together with the subfig package. I don't know what exactly  this implies.

Comment: I don't know how it was before, but with the current version from 2018 you can use `\namecref{<label>}` to get e.g. "fig.". So you can make your approach **clever** by defining `\newcommand{\csubref}[1]{\namecref{#1}~\subref{#1}}` and using `\csubref{fig:a}`. And as variant: `\newcommand{\Csubref}[1]{\nameCref{#1}~\subref{#1}}`.

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust the behaviour of `cleveref` as follows and then simply use `\cref{sub@fig:a}` in the text.

If you just use `subcaption` and look in the `.aux` file you will see that a `\label{fig:a}` in a `subfigure` produces to entries in the `.aux` file, one for `fig:a`, with printed value like `1a` and a one for `sub@fig:a` with two values `{a}{1}`.

When you load `cleveref` too, then two more labels are stored `fig:a@cref` and `sub@fig:a@cref`.  However by default they contain the same data and print `1a`.  You can modify the second one to just have the data for `a` by adapting the `subcaption` code.  You can then reference it via `\cref{sub@fig:a}` instead of `\cref{fig:a}`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{subcaption}{%
\renewcommand*\subcaption@@label[2]{%
  \@bsphack\begingroup
    \subcaption@ORI@label#1{#2}%
    \let\SK@\@gobbletwo
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname thesub\@captype\endcsname}%
    \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
      [subs\@captype][\arabic{sub\@captype}][\cref@result]%
      \csname thesub\@captype\endcsname}%
    \subcaption@ORI@label#1{sub@#2}%
  \endgroup\@esphack}%
}
\makeatother

\crefname{subsfigure}{fig.}{figs.}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-a}
        \caption{Figure 1a}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-b}
        \caption{Figure 1b}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Main figure caption}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

Using subcaption, I can refer to \ref{fig}, \ref{fig:a} or to
\subref{fig:a} alone.

Using cleverref, I can also refer to \cref{fig} and to \cref{fig:a},
and similaryl \cref{fig:b}.

Now I can refer to \cref{sub@fig:a} alone, and similarly
\cref{sub@fig:b} too.

\end{document}
```

The appropriate macro to modify is `\subcaption@@label` which is responsible for generating the two entries.  Just before the second entry it redefines `\@currentlabel`.  What I have done above is also add a redefinition for `\cref@currentlabel`.  I have done this so it associates a new type of `subsfigure`, and then `\crefname` can be used to define the associated text to put in front of the label when referenced.  The code should also work `subtables`.

Answer (score 6):

Imho changing subcaption to adapt to cleveref is the wrong strategy, it would be better if cleveref would rely in its redefinition of `\refstepcounter@noarg` etc on the current `\@currentlabel`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter

\def\refstepcounter@noarg#1{%
  \cref@old@refstepcounter{#1}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
    \noexpand\@currentlabel}} %changed

\def\refstepcounter@optarg[#1]#2{%
  \cref@old@refstepcounter{#2}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#2}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#2}][\cref@result]%
    \noexpand\@currentlabel}}% changed   

\makeatother    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-a}
        \caption{Figure 1a}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-b}
        \caption{Figure 1b}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Main figure caption}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

Using subcaption, I can link to \ref{fig}, \ref{fig:a} or to \subref{fig:a} alone.

Using cleverref, I can also link to \cref{fig} and to \cref{fig:a} and to \cref{sub@fig:a} alone.

\end{document}
```

[image]