# Reference multiple subfigures in one subref call

Tags: cross-referencing, subcaption

I am using `\subref` (provided by the `subcaption` package), and `\subref{somelabel}` works fine. I would like to reference multiple labels in the same call however, since I am using both parentheses and a bold typeface for the references, and constructing the style by hand would end up obfuscating my text a lot.

Is there any way to make `\subref{somelabel,someotherlabel}` work, or is there some other way to go about this without resetting the subref style and always adding the parentheses and bold typeface manually each time?

Comment: Does the posting [Combining cleveref and subref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333223/5001) help? The answers show how one might adapt the machinery of the `cleveref` package to make it possible to cross-reference multiple subfigures or subtables in a single `\cref` instruction.

Comment: All \subref does is \ref a different label name.  If you want something like (a-c) you will need to construct it from more then one \ref.